# How to Put a Session ID in a SOAP XML Packet

Tags: xml, session, soap, header

I am testing a SOAP endpoint with a Graphical tool. The whole reason behind the exercise is to get some consultants test the SOAP endpoint without actually coding it.

I initially loaded by WSDL and got all the available calls. Then logged in using the login call which returns a Session ID which I need to use in my consequent calls.
Following is the result I get from Login Call.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse
            xmlns="urn:ws.rsys.com">
            <result>
                <sessionId>xM7WOcf1I5Fq08SObqwYLRti3w</sessionId>
            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now my Log out call looks like below in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ws.rsys.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:logout/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to include the sessionId in order to successfully call the logout. Could someone help me with the right notation ?

Thanks
Dilanka

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the service WSDL and schema, as the authentication mechanism here looks custom.

The result may look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ws.rsys.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:SessionHeader>xM7WOcf1I5Fq08SObqwYLRti3w</ns1:SessionHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:logout/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```